# Question related to PoseArray and it's implementation

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roscpp, pathplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I need to implement Dijkstra's algorithm on a Map I have.

Coding part of my problem is done, however I am having trouble saving the path in a geometry_msgs/PoseArray.

Let's say I have an array(in c++) named prev which stores the shortest path from source to destination.

How can I use this path to publish a PoseArray and then visualise it on rViz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339453/question-related-to-posearray-and-it%27s-implementation./) by [Parth2851](https://answers.ros.org/users/48975/parth2851/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2019-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming you included the header files correctly and got a working CMakeLists and a nodehandle (nh).

```
pose_array_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseArray>("/my_pose_array", 1);

geometry_msgs::PoseArray my_pose_array;
my_pose_array.header.frame_id = "map"; // or other frame you wish to publish relative to.
std::vector<geometry_msgs::Pose> your_vector;
// push or insert to your vector
my_pose_array.poses = your_vector;

pose_array_pub.publish(my_pose_array);
```

You can otherwise manually push your pose array with e.g. my_pose_array.poses.push_back(my_pose)

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2019-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0